# Method Delay In NSURLSession Block

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlsession, xcode7, ios9

When I call this block:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:url
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {

                 _data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

                _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@°",([[[self.data objectForKey:@"main"] objectForKey:@"temp"] floatValue]) - 273.15)];

            NSLog(@"%@",self.data);


            }] resume];
```

The code inside the block takes a long time to execute, even though the NSLog gets called - what's going on? I've tried all sorts of solutions, but nothing is working.

Comment: why do you think it's taking a long time?

Comment: Do you  mean the label text updates after the log was called?

Comment: Too right @NilsZiehn and it happens a long time after..

Answer (score 1):

Always perform your UI update related task on main thread otherwise it take time to perform UI.

Like,

1. Updating Label text.
2. Set Image on ImageView.
3. Timer related operation.

So use below code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@°",([[[self.data objectForKey:@"main"] objectForKey:@"temp"] floatValue]) - 273.15)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@°",([[[self.data objectForKey:@"main"] objectForKey:@"temp"] floatValue]) - 273.15)];
}
```

When you set your label.

The reason:

You're probably not on the main thread and you should never update your UI from a different thread. Today iOS doesn't crash anymore when you do this, but it still 'laggs' behind.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS all the UI changes are to be made on the main thread and if you try to make any change in the UI in a block (which is executed on the background thread) it lags. You can use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` to execute the UI changes in the block.

Hope this will help you.